# Serialization error : StanfordNLP java library

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to make my own model using StanfordNLP java library programmatically.

"traindatacode-model.ser.gz" file is created but without any content. It is created correctly using following cmd command:

```
java -cp -Xmx1g stanford.ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop traindata.prop
```

Following code is used to do same thing programmatically but creates empty serialized file.

```
public class Buildmodel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String propPath = "C:\\Users\\kr277288\\Desktop\\traindata1.prop";
    String trainingfile ="C:\\Users\\kr277288\\Desktop\\traindata4labels.tsv";
    String serializePath = "C:\\Users\\kr277288\\Desktop\\NERtest\\testfiles\\traindatacode-model.ser.gz";
    Properties prop1= propFileToProperties(propPath);
    CRFClassifier crf1 = new CRFClassifier(prop1);
    crf1.serializeClassifier(crf1.flags.serializeTo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are trainingfile and serializePath being used? Are you adding them to prop1?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Both the parameters are specified in "traindata1.prop" file which is passed to prop1 using propPath. Also i have verified that all the flags are correctly loaded by extracting those parameters using prop1.

Comment: They are not used in this code currently. I used them earlier to verify it with "serializeTo" and "trainfile" values in prop1.

Comment: You are not using the same property file for both cases (traindata.prop and traindata1.prop), can you post the content of your property file ?